# PHP CURL Array filter - Date Variable

Tags: php, variables, filter

```
<?php

    $today = date("y-m-d");
    $filter = ['2019-06-18'];

    // Api Request
    $a = ordersRequest("statistics/list", array("idapp" => 11111));

    $links = $a['statistics']['grp_date'];
    $filtered = array_filter($links, function ($item) use ($filter) {
    return in_array($item['date'], $filter);
    });
    print_r($filtered);

     ?>
```

This Works:

```
$filter = ['2019-06-02'];
```

But how can i get the current date in this variable?

```
$filter = ['$today'];
$filter = [$today];
$filter = date("y-m-d");
```

Don't works for me

Comment: @user3783243 Code works with $filter = ['2019-06-18']; <- manual version. But with this filter variable not...$filter = date("y-m-d");  How can i fix this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$filter = date("y-m-d");
```

is not the same as

```
$filter = ['2019-06-02'];
```

for 2 reasons.

1. `[]` makes an array, `date()` returns a string.
2. `y` is a two digit representation of the year. `Y` should be used for the 4 digit representation.

   ```
   $filter = [date('Y-m-d')];
   ```